# Why my Instagram API Permissions Decline with Policy Violation Red Tags for Social Media Marketing Business Model

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, permission-denied

We are developing web app with business model of Social Media Marketing, our app let people who consider them self as influencers, specifically instagram influencers can join us and share their own portfolio about working with brand as endorsement project which they share on their instagram account, and some brand will see their profile on our web app if its fit with their needs then collaborate with them for brand campaign.

we are submitting for permission to instagram but always declined with instagram with Policy Violation response, we even not getting the basic permission for displaying my user own status and media

here's the response:

> **General issues:**
>
> **Policy Violation (Ad network, Influencer network, Other related)**: Your app should not attempt to build an ad network on Instagram, nor
> transfer any data that you receive from us (including anonymous,
> aggregate, or derived data) to any ad network, data broker, influencer
> network, or other advertising or monetization-related service. In
> working to build a high quality platform, we ask that you comply with
> our Platform Policy
> (http://wwww.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/).
>
> **Feedback from your Reviewer**: Thank you for providing such a detailed and descriptive screencast. Unfortunately, your submission
> violates our Instagram policy, please revisit this page
> (https://www.instagram.com/developer/). Thank you and please resubmit!

why would this happen? considering there are many competitors in our country with the same business model but they have instagram permission.

we knowing about instagram new restriction from june 2016, and will eliminate the permission that violate their new policy, isn't that means all of our competitor will not have the permission again? but they still have the permission till now

Comment: Try reapplying with a carefully worded description of your business. If you use certain words like "Influencer" you'll be denied instantly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer support question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite straighforward that you are unable to express your work.

If it has gray areas which Instagram doesn't like at all, you'll definately be declined. Be clear and specific. What's the purpose of life of your application?
Look in more details about others' privacy policy how they pick the proper wording. Here are good examples who succeeds:

- http://picbear.com/terms-of-service
- https://vibbi.com/member/terms-of-service

Many of the applicants rejected because of their intention, so obvious. Even you are planning to use Google Adwords in your website express that too. Don't assume.

Write what you do, do what you write