# Is it possible to use Instagram API in order to make a user list according to the number of followers?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Instagram API permission is strict now and I want to know whether the tool my company will make can get the permission from Instagram or not, because it may not suit with the 3 valid use case.

We are an offshore company which develops application. 
One clients ( PR or Advertisement company) asked us to make an app which finds  influencers(the user who has many followers) on Instagram so that the clients can ask the influencer to advertise their products.

We want to make a influencer searching tool. Lets, say if you search with #Chocolate, the list of users who have posted photos with #Chocolate will show up, and we want to sort out the list according to the number of followers.
[image: the image of search and search result]

Referring to the valid use case for Instagram, which case may be suitable for the app we want to make?

Also, by one-off project, what does it mean? We are an offshore company and get orders from a client which want us to make a tool for them. If we just make it, and will not sell or use the application again, would it be "one-off" project?
In order to avoid one-off project, do we need to keep selling or offering the app ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API call to make this. You have to make a series of API calls to get all the posts for hashtag, this will have user_id and name. Then for each user you have to make another API call to get followers count. And then you have sort the results and make query for `>3000`

For example #chocolate has 1 million posts, so to get all 1 million posts you have make about 50000 API calls (u get 20 post per API call), and then you have to make 1 million user_info API calls to get follower counts, so 1050000 API calls total and you have 5000/hr API calls limit. So to complete this operation it will take you 9 days.

This will be a one off project if u do for a client use, you have to make a platform or service for this feature and have your client (and others) login and use the service.

In any case, the project is unrealistic to implement due to the limitation of APIs

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I asked engineers whether they can make this possible and they said yes, technically. However, I see your points and seems difficult, considering the rate limit. 

And I understood that this may be a one-off project, so we will consider offering as a service, thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231067/why-my-instagram-api-permissions-decline-with-policy-violation-red-tags-for-soci

For getting the permission from Instagram, I understand that I have to be really careful about the choice of words when I submit the request. In order to make this kind of influencer finding tool, is there any other website that I can learn and imitate the wording? 

I really appreciate your answer!