# Instagram: Is it possible to get user's name, follower numbers, and search photos with #tag?

Tags: json, instagram, instagram-api

I once asked this question.

[Is it possible to use Instagram API in order to make a user list according to the number of followers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627363/is-it-possible-to-use-instagram-api-in-order-to-make-a-user-list-according-to-th)

And I am not a programmer, just a salesman.

And it seems like we cannot make this influencer finding tool by using "official" Instagram API. So I have looked for other solutions and found a way to get data from Instagram by using other API and JSON. 
Please refer to these links.

https://github.com/whizzzkid/instagram-reverse-proxy

[How can I get a user's media from Instagram without authenticating as a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user/33783840#33783840)

[Obtaining Instagram Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932689/obtaining-instagram-access-token/37933461#37933461)

My goal is creating an influencer finding tool, so I need to find photos with #tag and make user list accordingly to the number of followers of the user.

My question is;

1 Is it possible to get data such as user name, follower numbers, photos with certain #tag? by using non-official API and JSON?

2 And suppose we made it, then Instagram will find out our products and ban our accounts or service? It seems they do not allow us to use non-official API.

I would appreciate it if you could teach me whether we can make it or not, in a way that you talk to the person who does not know much about JSON or so.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using unofficial API is always risky, its against their terms and policy.

You can use official APIs to make get this info.

You first have to make hashtag API , which gives you posts with username (no follower count), then for each user, you have make another API call to get user info, this will give you follower counts, bio and other details.

The 2 APIs needed are below, you need `public_content` scope permission and have to get your app approved by instagram and go to live mode.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Since once you answered to my question, I thought there was a technical problem such as call limit. Besides that, getting permission from Instagram is said to be really difficult, so I wanted to see if using unofficial API is good choice or not.

Either way, this project seems tough, I will report to my boss. Thanks a lot!